# How to receive MSMQ Messages

Tags: msmq, netmsmqbinding, msmq-wcf

Whats the best way to receive MSMQ messages.

I used the following code, but after receiving MSMQ messages not getting removed in Queue

```
var msgEnumerator = myQueue.GetMessageEnumerator2();
            var messages = new List<System.Messaging.Message>();
            while (msgEnumerator.MoveNext(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)))
            {
                var msg = myQueue.ReceiveById(msgEnumerator.Current.Id, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
                messages.Add(msg);
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.Capacity; i++)
                {
                    String DataMessages = messages[i].ToString();
                }
```

But i cant receive messages.

How to receive those messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use asynchronous MessageQueue.BeginPeek to start listening on the queue:

```
queue.BeginPeek();
```

Then register a handler with the MessageQueue.PeekCompleted event:

```
queue.PeekCompleted += new PeekCompletedEventHandler(MessageHasBeenReceived);
```

Then in your handler use MessageQueue.EndPeek to access the message. Remember to call BeginPeek again.

```
private void MessageHasBeenReceived(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get message
    var msg = queue.EndPeek(e.AsyncResult);

    // Do message processing here
    ....

    // Remove message from queue
    queue.ReceiveById(msg.Id);

    // Listen for more messages
    queue.BeginPeek();
}
```

See here for [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.peekcompleted.aspx) example.